# Custom keyboard layout behaves like last selected

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm trying to create a custom layout in XKB following instructions given in stack exchange answers and other tutorials. I have the following in the file `my`:

```
default alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

  name[Group1]="MyLayout";

  key <AC01> { [ UE700 ] };
  key <AC02> { [ UE701 ] };
  key <AC03> { [ UE702 ] };
  key <AC04> { [ UE703 ] };
  key <AC05> { [ UE704 ] };
  key <AC06> { [ UE705 ] };
  key <AC07> { [ UE706 ] };
  key <AC08> { [ UE707 ] };
  key <AC09> { [ UE708 ] };
  key <AC10> { [ UE709 ] };
  key <AC11> { [ UE70A ] };
  key <AD03> { [ UE70B ] };
};
```

I added blocks to the `evdev.lst` and `evdev.xml` files:

```
// evdev.lst
! layout
  my              MyLayout
  us              English (US)

// evdev.xml
<layout>
    <configItem>
        <name>my</name>
        <shortDescription>my</shortDescription>
        <description>MyLayout</description>
        <languageList>
            <iso639Id>myl</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
    </configItem>
    <variantList/>
</layout>
```

I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data` prior to testing. The layout is visible in my system settings as `MyLayout` and I can add it with no apparent issue. However, when I select it as the active layout, its symbol is dark gray and it behaves like the layout immediately before it in the dropdown list. If my list goes `English (US)`, `Hebrew`, `MyLayout`, my custom layout will behave exactly like the Hebrew layout. If I remove Hebrew, it will behave exactly like English (US). I'm fresh out of ideas on this and am not seeing an issue with my syntax.

```
locale is C
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     my
variant:    basic
options:    compose:ralt,lv3:caps_switch
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+my(basic)+inet(evdev)+compose(ralt)+level3(caps_switch)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+my(basic)+inet(evdev)+compose(ralt)+level3(caps_switch)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Comment: what did you add in `evdev` to go along with your `evdev.{lst,xml}` entries?  the lst/xml files are only descriptions, `evdev` is where the rules to load your layout are defined.

Comment: aha, that must be my issue. I added nothing. Looking at it now, the syntax is not clear to me. I'm guessing I want to add the line `*    my    =    +???`, where ??? is some mumbo jumbo I'm not following

Comment: Your `my` file only defines a few keys. Possibly the fact that it's incomplete matters. You may want to try to add `include "us(basic)"` before your key definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the actual rule in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev`; the `evdev.{lst,xml}` files are only descriptions.

My best guess is that you need something like the following:

```
# existing lines
! model         layout          variant         =       symbols
  *             ben             basic           =       pc+in(ben)
# your additions
  *             my              basic           =       pc+my(basic)
```

I'm assuming your `my` file is `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/my`.  The first 3 columns are matching XKB input parameters (here, any `-model`, `-layout my`, `-variant basic`).  The last column defines the symbols rule in terms of symbol files to load, in the format `file(clause)` (multiple files separated by `+`).  Symbol files are all in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.

Try that -- you can test with something like this to make sure it's working (note the `+my(basic)` in the `xkb_symbols` line):

```
$ setxkbmap -layout my -variant basic -print
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+my(basic)+inet(evdev)"     };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

One problem is that I'm not sure your `my` definitions won't conflict with an existing layout.  If this is a completely new layout, you should probably call it something else to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Okay, this is informative, but the modification to evdev doesn't cause any change in behavior. Do I also have to edit base and base.{lst/xml}?

Comment: no, evdev is the current rules in use.  can you see the changes with the `setxkbmap` command i've shown?  if so the new rule is working.  if not try again with `-verbose 10` and update your question with the output.

Comment: It looks like the symbols are being included

Comment: @AlexClough ok that output looks pretty sane.  the `-print` makes it a simple test (good first step!).  run `setxkbmap -query` to see your current settings then add your new layout to it (should look like `setxkbmap -layout us,my -variant ,basic -option compose:ralt,lv3:caps_switch` or some such -- without `-print` it will try to load the layout).

Comment: silence on the command line. Should that command have caused the layout to appear in the selection dropdown? Might it be relevant that the unicode points I included in the layout are in a private use area?

Comment: dunno? probably not.  rerun `setxkbmap -query` to see what's loaded now; it should match.  test switching with your capslock key. does your custom layout get loaded?  i think you'll have to log out / log in to pick up changes in the indicator, but `setxkbmap` should be enough to see if it's actually working first.

Comment: if the changes aren't sticking with `setxkbmap` long enough to test, run `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false` to disable GNOME/unity keyboard handling temporarily (rerun with `true` to reenable).

Comment: it is getting loaded according to `setxkbmap -query`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56017/discussion-between-quixotic-and-alex-clough).

Comment: The `evdev` file itself says, `// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - IT WAS AUTOGENERATED BY merge.py FROM rules/*.part`. So it's not the real origin of the definition. But in the doc of python `evdev` lib I cannot find where are the *.part files should be put. At last I have to use `xkbcomp`.